# TokBox Publisher failed to publish in a reasonable amount of time

Tags: webrtc, mobile-safari, opentok, tokbox

I am implementing a video recording for my web application using OpenTok's js library.

Currently using .NET and JavaScript SDK to record the video.
https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/dot-net/

The video recording is working on Chrome and Firefox, but it is not working on Mobile Safari 12.3.1, resulting in so many errors. 
It works sometimes, but most of the time, it results in an error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find the reason?